# Laravel 5.4 form routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a scenario wherein a renewal contract can have multiple devices. I add the devices in the view blade of the renewal using a modal. The problem is that the submit button is not working. The 'store' function for the device is in the contract controller, so it creates a device then associates it to the current contract.
My routes:

```
    Route::post('/storeDevice', 'RenewalController@storeDevice')->name('renewals.storeDevice');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
Route::resource('supports', 'SupportController');
Route::resource('tests', 'TestController');
Route::resource('renewals', 'RenewalController');
Route::resource('devices', 'DeviceController');
```

My modal

```
<div class="modal fade container" id="addDevice">
 {!! Form::open([ 'method'=>'POST', 'action' => ['RenewalController@storeDevice', $renewal] ]) !!}

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">New Device</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </p>
        <p>
            {!! Form::label('startDate', 'Warranty Start:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::date('startDate', null) !!}
            &nbsp
            {!! Form::label('endDate', 'Warranty End:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::date('endDate', null) !!}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Submit </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
    </div>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you include images of code, and not the code itself? By the way, tell your boss to buy you a legit Windows copy, man.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow to please include the code in your question instead of references to images.

Comment: i am sorry, I can edit this right? but still you did not aswer my question sad

Comment: @vladjamir What the error shown? anyway in your form should include `{{ Form::token() }}`

Comment: @Sovary there is no error shown, it's just that when I click the cubmit button nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some solutions

1. Use `{{ Form::submit('Submit ', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}` instead raw html button. Or
2. Add id to form then use js to click submit button

   `function form_submit() {
   document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
   }`

then call function in onclick event button to submit.
Try this two solutions hope it work